# Given a nonzero column vector $A$=$[a_1 a_2.......a_n]^T$.how to Find the non zero eigen values and eigen vectors for A$A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a nonzero column vector $A$=$[a_1  a_2.......a_n]^T$. Find the non zero eigen values and eigen vectors for $A$$A^T$.

I have no idea.what theorem should I apply or what I have to do to solve this. I know that fact $A$$A^T$ and $A^T$$A$ have the same eigen values and if $A$ and $B$ be square matrix of same order the $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigen values. Is it related to this statements?

Comment: I suggest you take an example. Take $A = [1,2]^T$. What is $AA^T$? What are its non-zero eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Now change $A$ to something else and check : find a pattern, and see if you can generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}}$

This is a well known exercise in eigenvalue-eigenvector, for which you actually do not need to start with solving the equation $\det(\lambda I - B) = 0$ to determine eigenvalues (as you usually do). The special structure of $AA^T$ as a product of two rank one vectors allows us to have the following shortcut.

Since $\rank(A) = 1$, $\rank(AA^T) = \rank(A) = 1$, hence $AA^T$ has one and only one non-zero eigenvalue, and all the remaining $n - 1$ eigenvalues are $0$.

Now note $A^TA = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 \neq 0$ is a scalar, denoted it by $\lambda$, hence
\begin{align*}
(AA^T)A = AA^TA = (A^TA)A = \lambda A.
\end{align*}
This shows $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^T$, and $A$ is the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for this proof its like perfect  I could have never came up with that. But as Teresa Lisbon suggested the pattern was clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{w}\in\Bbb R^n$ are represented as column vectors. Recall that the *dot product* of $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$  may be written as $\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{v}^\intercal\boldsymbol{w}$.

Your matrix is of the form $M=\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^\intercal$ where $\boldsymbol{v}\in\Bbb R^n$.

First, note that
$$
M\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^\intercal\boldsymbol{v}=\lVert\boldsymbol{v}\rVert^2\cdot\boldsymbol{v}\tag{1}
$$
Here, we have used the identity $\boldsymbol{v}^\intercal\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}=\lVert\boldsymbol{v}\rVert^2$.

Next, suppose $\boldsymbol{w}$ is any vector orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{v}$, so that $\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{w}=0$. Then
$$
M\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^\intercal\boldsymbol{w}=0\cdot\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{O}\tag{2}
$$
Do you see how the equations (1) and (2) relate to the eigenvalue/eigenvector problem?